# Actionscript 3 adding RadioButton to RadioGroup

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-builder

Im kind of working a little in ActionScript 3.0 now. And after I found out I could write the code in Flash builder 4.6 and do the gui in Flash professional, thing got much smoother.

but as the title says, I have few RadioButtons on stage called rb1, rb2. Since Im coding in flash builder I need to reference them by  writing : 
Public var rb1:RadioButton;
and so on...
That's not a problem, Now I Can reference to it by writing rb1.alpha / label/ or whatever I like. But get that button added to a group or reference to a group is the problem.
If i make a group like : public var group123:RadioButtonGroup;
and write group123.addRadioButton(rb1); it's not working.
If someon wondering why I wan't to do it, it's because I want to set up a switch for the RadioButton for better code structure.

Hope anyone can help me!! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RadioButtons don't add to RadioButtonGroup as children.
Use properties **group** or **groupName** of RadioButton.

```
rb1.group = group123;
rb2.group = group123;
```

Comment: Thank's for the answer, but if it just was that easy. I know it is supposed to work, but whatever I do.
Writing rb1.group = group123;
will throw following error:
MainClass.as connected properly
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
 at fl.controls::RadioButton/set group()
 at MainClass/radioKnappOppsett()
 at MainClass()

Comment: Never mind mate! I did something, wrong:) I will not mark your answer as right mate:))! And thank's!

Comment: May be you forgot to create your `radiobuttons? rb1 = new RadioButton()`

Comment: See [help and example](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/controls/RadioButtonGroup.html#includeExamplesSummary)